# Creating an Arc Path in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics

I am trying to create an arc path in xcode and this is my code.

```
CGPathAddArc(thePath,NULL,100,200,300,200,100,YES);
```

This code works but it creates a very weird arc. I was wondering what each number in this code represents. I am trying to create an arc in the form of a half circle. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please give us more information, tell us what you want to achieve, and what results you want, and why the results you are getting are wrong so we can try to help

Comment: If you want to know what each parameter means, read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathAddArc) (which is really easy to look up by going to http://developer.apple.com/ios ), the first parameter is the path ref you are building. A transform is next (you've passed NULL).

Then, for the numbers, which are all CGFloats:

- x The x-coordinate of the center point of the arc.
- y The y-coordinate
  of the center point of the arc.
- r The radius of the arc.
- startAngle
  The angle (in radians) that determines the starting point of the arc,
  measured from the x-axis in the current user space.
- endAngle The
  angle (in radians) that determines the ending point of the arc,
  measured from the x-axis in the current user space.

and ending with a "clockwise" bool.

Comment: [Here's the Wikipedia definition of an Affine Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation_matrix) and they can be set up using [these Quartz 2D API's](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html).